# WooCommerce and Theme templates

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I want to customize WooCommerce plugin. Which file can I copy from WooCommerce plugin to theme folder?

Please let me know about the name of the files?

Comment: Only the files in `templates/`. The files will have a comment at the top telling you if they can be copied.

Answer (score 0):

Read the official docs: [Template structure & Overriding templates via a theme](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/template-structure/)